# Oracle Stored Procedure Failed With Bound Parameters

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper, parameterized-query

I have a stored procedure within a package in Oracle that takes in several `NUMBER` types as arguments, and works without issue when integers are explicitly passed.

However, when utilizing bound parameters (in SQL Developer), I get the error `Error report - Missing defines`. When running it in PHP, it fails silently. Given the security benefits of using bound parameters, I would prefer not to concatenate a query in PHP and do it that way (yes, I could use `intval()` and it would handle that) because this issue goes beyond just packages with integer parameters.

This works, both in the successful run and verified database changes.

```
BEGIN package_name.procedure_name(
    1,
    2
); END;
```

However, this does not.

```
BEGIN package_name.procedure_name(
    :VARIABLE_1,
    :VARIABLE_2
); END;
```

And neither does this:

```
BEGIN package_name.procedure_name(
    VARIABLE_1 => :VARIABLE_1,
    VARIABLE_2 => :VARIABLE_2
); END;
```

Running the debugging in SQL Developer provides logic to declare the types then pass them as variables, but adding the binding there fails as well.

Any ideas as to why the error is produced, given that the procedure runs without a problem with the static arguments?

Answer (score 0):

You may use in this manner:

```
SQL> variable VARIABLE_1 number;
SQL> variable VARIABLE_2 number;
SQL> BEGIN 
package_name.procedure_name(
    :VARIABLE_1,
    :VARIABLE_2
); 
END;/
```

Comment: Ultimately, this needs to get run with PHP (I'm sorry if that wasn't clear), so how would I do that following this logic?

Comment: @kchason as i could understand, you asked from the point of SQL Developer, sorry but i don't know about relation to PHP.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that though as a first step, though you're naming `VARIABLE_1`, and binding `:VARIABLE_1`, from what I know, that won't work...